# Python Counter doesn't count

Tags: python, if-statement, counter

```
import urllib2
f=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.mbnet.com.pl/dl.txt")
list = range(1,50)
counter={}

for lines in f:
    tab_lines=lines.split(" ")
    formated_tab=tab_lines[-1].strip().split(',')
    #print formated_tab
    for i in formated_tab:
        if i in list:
            counter[i]+=1
print counter.items()
```

My `counter` doesn't work and I don't know why :(

This is a list of lottery numbers. I would like count how many times drawn each number.

Comment: Don't use list as a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
counter[i] = counter.get(i, 0) + 1
```

You can also try `collections.defaultdict`:

```
counter = defaultdict(int)
```

So you final version should be look like this:

```
import urllib2
from collections import defaultdict

f=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.mbnet.com.pl/dl.txt")
list = range(1,50)
counter=defaultdict(int)  # use defaultdict here

for lines in f:
    tab_lines=lines.split(" ")
    formated_tab=tab_lines[-1].strip().split(',')
    for i in formated_tab:
        if int(i) in list:
            counter[i] += 1  # don't worry, be happy :)
sumall=sum(counter.values())
for number, value in counter.items():
    print ('Number {} drawn {} times and it is {}% of all').format(number,value,100*value/sumall)
```

I'll give you an example to show what `collections.defaultdict` does here:

```
>>> from collections import defauldict
>>> a = {}
>>> a['notexist']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'notexist'
>>> b = defaultdict(int)
>>> b['notexist']
0
```

`class collections.defaultdict([default_factory[, ...]])`
defaultdict is a subclass of the built-in dict class, so don't be scared, but you can do more with it. Once you specified the `default_factory` variable, when the key is not exist, `defaultdict` will supply one for you according to the `default_factory`. Note this magic will only happen when you using `dict['key']` or `dict.__getitem__(key)`.

The doucumetaion is here: [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Thank you for show me this feature :) and explain how it's work :) I will be use that in future :)

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing *strings* with *integers*. Your `if` test never matches:

```
if i in list:
```

because each `i` is a string. Your `list` variable on the other hand, contains integers:

```
list = range(1,50)
```

Convert `i` to an integer to test against other integers:

```
if int(i) in list:
```

Some other remarks:

- `list` is not a good variable name; you are masking the [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).
- You could just test if `i` falls in a range by using comparison operators against the start and end values:

  ```
  if 1 <= int(i) < 50:
  ```

  which would be faster as you don't have to scan through the list each time.
- You cannot assume that the key is already present in `counter`. You'd have to test first or use `counter.get()` to return a default. For example:

  ```
  counter[i] = counter.get(i, 0) + 1
  ```
- To count your values, you could use the standard library [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

  ```
  from collections import Counter

  counter = Counter()

  for lines in f:
      tab_lines = lines.split()  # note, no argument!
      formatted_tab = map(int, tab_lines[-1].split(','))
      counter.update(i for i in formatted_tab if 0 < i < 50)

  print counter.most_common()
  ```

  In my testing, I didn't see any numbers in that file that where outside the range of 0 to 50 (exclusive), so you can probably get away with just `counter.update(formatted_tab)`.

Comment: And besides that, overwriting `list` is not a good idea, and `counter[i]+=1` will throw an error because `counter[i]` hasn't been set yet...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [Martin Pieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30233671/4408382) there is another problem. You're accessing a dictionary key that doesn't exist in the dictionary. Instead of

`counter[i]+=1`

you should use something like

`counter[i] = counter.get(i, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

So much thank you guys !

I finished this code :) !

```
import urllib2
f=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.mbnet.com.pl/dl.txt")
list = range(1,50)
counter={}

for lines in f:
    tab_lines=lines.split(" ")
    formated_tab=tab_lines[-1].strip().split(',')
    for i in formated_tab:
        if int(i) in list:
                counter[i] = counter.get(i, 0) + 1
sumall=sum(counter.values())
for number, value in counter.items():
    print ('Number {} drawn {} times and it is {}% of all ').format(number,value,100*value/sumall)
```